# 'darken()' and 'rgba()', Are these functions in css?

Tags: css

In the below css code,

```
@import "compass/css3";

.navigation a:hover {
  background: darken(deepskyblue, 2%);
}

 .navigation a { 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  }
```

`darken()` and `rgba()` show function like syntax.

Are these functions or preprocessor macros? Is there a pre-req install required before running these functions?

*Note: CSS beginner*

Comment: google compass css3 darken and it's the first answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of both:

`rgba()` is a [native CSS3 function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()) which takes the following arguments:

```
rgba(<red>, <green>, <blue>, <alpha>)
```

However, what you're seeing is [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), a CSS Pre-processor which provides [additional colour manipulation controls](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html). `darken()` is a Sass-native method which will return a hex-code colour based on an input colour and a darken amount (given as a percentage).

Whilst the `rgba()` in Sass can work in exactly the same way as the native CSS function, it will also handle hex colours, such as:

```
rgba(#000, 0.5) // Compiles to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

In practice this is super-useful as colours are most often supplied as hex-values, and are abstracted through variables which describe the semantics, for example:

```
.error-box {
  background-color: rgba($color-error, 0.2);
  color: darken($color-error, 10%);
}
```

The intentions of the style choices are much clearer that they would be in the compiled CSS.

Comment: Before I run `darken` or `rgba`, Do I need to install SASS?

Comment: Can we write SASS syntax in a file with .css extension?

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 2):

This is actually LESS feature [LESS](https://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken) further detail please click the link.

```
darken(hsl(90, 80%, 50%), 20%)
```

For RGBA it was CSS3 `#p1 {background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);}   /* red with opacity */

Comment: It's not less, `@import "compass/css3"` - Compass is a Sass-based authoring framework

Answer (score 1):

This is not a part of css, but rather of css-preprocessor like [LESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) or [SASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29).

In this case it's sass (as seen by the usage of [compass/css3](http://compass-style.org/)): http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

That is [`LESS`](http://lesscss.org/) (or `SASS`, as mentioned) preprocessor syntax. `darken` generates and returns darker version of supplied color, `rgba` returns color, built from four components (r, g, b, a, obviously).